# Electronegative - Electropositive atoms can attract ions?

Tags: batteries, electrochemistry, ions

Well I was just wondering how a copper-zinc battery works, with electrolyte an equilibrium of water and NaOH. It says that NaOH is dissolved (I understand that) into water forming H$_4$O$_8$Na+ ions and H$_4$O$_8$OH- ions. But how do those ions get attracted towards the anode and the cathode of the battery (H$_4$O$_8$Na+ attracted to cathode, H$_4$O$_8$OH- attracted to the anode)? Zinc molecules and Copper molecules are not dipole molecules.

Comment: You wouldn't use NaOH in a zinc-copper battery. That would form insoluble zinc hydroxide and gum up your battery. Are you sure you mean NaOH and not NaCl?

Comment: Yes sorry NaCl is the salt I use unstead of NaOH which is a base